# Can somebody update the search section of the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

Under the Stackoverflow FAQ the section entitled "Are there any search options?" could use an update. I have to search on how to search on stackoverflow because the search options are hidden so well. The natural place for this kind of thing is in the FAQ. Basically it just needs to have a summary of https://stackoverflow.com/search. Also, a link to the above linked search page on the home page would be nice. Here is my suggestion:

```
Are there any search options?

Indeed there are. To search, type in the box at the top right of every page 
and press Enter. For example, 'apples oranges' will return any questions or 
answers containing "apples" or "oranges". If that's not specific enough, 
you can narrow your search even further. You can narrow your search to specific 
tags like this: '[tag] apples oranges' or this: '[tag] [another-tag] apples 
oranges' or to a phrase like this: '"apples oranges"' or to ensure that the 
words appear in the results '+apples +oranges'. Advanced Super Ninja Search 
Options are available at https://stackoverflow.com/search. … but you must 
first snatch this pebble from my hand, grasshopper.
```

I am not sure what that last part means but it must be important to somebody or it wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ now links to the advanced search options at the bottom.